# matlab - creating matrix with zero rows and one on index

Tags: matlab, matrix

i have a vector `a = [1; 6; 8]`
and want to create a matrix with `n` columns and `size(a,1)` rows.

Each i'th row is all zeros but on the `a(i)` index is one.

`>> make_the_matrix(a, 10)`

```
ans = 
   1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `sparse`

```
 numCol = 10; % number of colums in output matrix, should not be greater than max(a)
 mat = sparse( 1:numel(a), a, 1, numel(a), numCol );
```

if you want a full matrix just use

```
 full(mat)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my first thought:

```
a = [1;6;8];
nCols = 10;
nRows = length(a); 
M = zeros(nRows,nCols);

M(:,a) = eye(nRows)
```

Basically the eye is assigned to the right columns of the matrix.